# Windows error on program start-up

Tags: windows, delphi

I have an application written in Delphi XE3 (Originally Delphi 7) with a MySQL database. It was running on 5 computers on a network. Two of the computers were on windows 7 while 3 were still windows XP. The client recently upgraded the 3 windows XP computers to windows 7 x64 (3 brand-new identical machines). The program is running fine on one of the new computers but on the other 2 I get the error message "A problem caused the program to stop working. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available". The program seems to crash at the end of the FormActivate procedure after it had verified the password and connected to the database. The MySQL server is up and running. I can access the database on the problem machines locally and remotely successfully.

I have searched the Internet and some websites suggest that this error is a protective mechanism from Windows triggered by a thread to system files, indefinite loops or memory problems – none of which are applicable to my program.

I have since reformatted the 2 problem computers and reinstalled Windows 7 again but it did not solve the problem.

The DependencyWalker output on both problem and working machines (and on my development machine) are identical :

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>
> Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

With regard to different CPU types - in all instances the application is x86 and the rest of the modules are x64. This could be a 32-bit-64-bit problem but the program is running on all the machines except for 2 problem machines.

The Windows Event Viewer reports the following error:

> Faulting application name: February_2014.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52fa3b19
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116
>
> Exception code: 0x0eedfade
>
> Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
>
> Faulting process id: 0x1510
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cf28a57840f88d
>
> Faulting application path: C:\dgpa dgr\February_2014.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: bd26ca27-9498-11e3-9479-7c050710b013

I have searched the Internet (and Stackoverflow) for KERNELBASE.dll but could not find anything useful.

I have asked for help on Windows Technet without success
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ef52b2e1-237d-436f-952f-7cdecdb48337/a-problem-caused-the-program-to-stop-working-windows-will-close-the-program-and-notify-you-if-a?forum=w7itprogeneral

The program is running without the hitch on my Windows 7 x64 development machine so I cannot replicate the problem/error that I am experiencing at my client. Has anybody had a similar problem? Any suggestions for the cause/trigger of the Error and how to solve it?

UPDATE

I got the following report from madExcept but I have no idea what it means

[image]

Comment: add logging to your application, or use a MadExcept/Eurekalog tool...

Comment: Dependency Walker is misleading you. Bitness is not the problem. Bitness mismatches don't lead to access violations. Simply put, you have a bug in your program's startup code. You need to find it. Step 1 is to add madExcept.

Comment: It seems to me that a designtime DB component (Datasnap?) is failing (check for Active property set to true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a ClientDataSet in your application you need to deploy `midas.dll` with your application, or you have to manually add the `MidasLib` unit to your project's uses clause (for example)

```
program Project1;

uses
  MidasLib,
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};
```

For a detailed explanation see the [article of Cary Jensen](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29297) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot from madExcept is telling you that your program is raising an exception at startup, before you call `Application.Run`. The root of the exception is in the call to `Application.CreateForm` made in your project file.

The top-level exception handler is contained in the main application message loop that is implemented in `Application.Run`. Because you have not yet started the main application message loop, there is no exception handler.

This means that the exception leaks out of your application and the system has to handle it as best it can.

I don't know how to fix your specific problem, but the madExcept diagnostics tell you where to start looking. Ideally you would like to be able to debug this scenario in the IDE. Once you can do that it will be much easier to track down.

Fundamentally, if you leak exceptions out of your startup code, you will encounter such error dialogs.

Comment: ... further, you know that the constructor of one of your forms is opening a database cursor, and failing

Comment: @David, thankyou for the advice. The program runs without exception on my machine in the IDE. I've got nothing to debug. I will strip the FormActivate procedure down and build it up in piece by piece testing between builds until I find the source of the exception.

Comment: Did you try debugging on a machine which fails.

Comment: In any case, it's surely over to you now. What more are you looking for at this question?

Answer (score 0):

I know of a few things that could be potential sources of the issue. First is the space (blank) in the path name where the application is running. Trying moving app to a subdirectory with no spaces in the path name. Second try running in Admin mode if you are not already. The answer that references "midas.dll" is another one. With the additional warning that Delphi used to install a copy of midas.dll in the Windows\System32 directory. Make sure that your version of midas.dll came with the version of Delphi you wrote the code in (and make sure that there isn't another older copy being found before the one you intended. Depends.exe can help show the path to the dll it loaded. Also have you tried running the app using "XP Compatibility"? Does the issue go away? Also have problems with DB components on a DataModule form in Delphi before. If you have a DB component with a AutoConenct on (or Streamed connection), it can cause unusual errors. Best to leave it disconnected and connect it in your source code at runtime. Last thing to try, look at the Windows services and see if the Performance Logs are running prior to launching your app. A weird one, but I've seen it.